# Unable to get animations working with react-native-reanimated 3

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to make a generic 'container' component that I can use around the app as a 'fade in' view. Here's the component:

```
import Animated, { FadeIn, Layout } from 'react-native-reanimated';

import { StyledProps } from '@models/styled-props';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export interface AnimatedViewProps extends StyledProps {
  className: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const AnimatedView = ({ children, className, style }: AnimatedViewProps) => {
  return (
    <Animated.View entering={FadeIn.duration(400)} layout={Layout.springify()}>
      <View className={`${className}`} style={style}>
        {children}
      </View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default AnimatedView;
```

I'm then using this in another container with some NativeWind styling

```
const StyledContainer = ({
  className,
  children,
  colour = 'quinary',
}: StyledContainerProps) => {
  return (
    <AnimatedView
      className={`m-2 p-4 rounded-lg ${BgColour[colour]} ${className}`}>
      {children}
    </AnimatedView>
  );
};
```

This seems like a pretty simple set up, however these components appear immediately with no animations.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@backpackapp-io/react-native-toast": "^0.8.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.6",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.9",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "i18next": "^22.4.15",
    "intl-pluralrules": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "p-queue": "^7.3.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.2.2",
    "react-native": "0.72.0-rc.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-google-recaptcha-v2": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-localize": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "^6.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^12.0.2",
    "timed-cache": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

.babelrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    'module:react-native-dotenv',
    'nativewind/babel',
    [
      require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
      {
        root: ['./'],
        alias: {
          '@components': './src/components',
          '@screens': './src/screens',
          '@assets': './src/assets',
          '@hooks': './src/hooks',
          '@utils': './src/utils',
          '@comms': './src/comms',
          '@models': './src/models',
          '@context': './src/context',
          '@enums': './src/enums',
          '@translations': './src/translations',
          '@root': './',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

I've tried on an iOS simulator and Android emulator, and also a physical device. No animations.

I am using a Toast lib in the app that uses react-native-animated and the animations for the toasts are working no problem.